# Making Custom Url in Yii 1.1.17

Tags: php, yii, url-routing, yii-url-manager

I am facing a problem in making custom URL using Yii framework. I need to make custom URL in the format like "category/product".

The category URL slug and product URL slug comes from the database.

Which rule should I implement to make it happen. I am pretty confused about it.

I have the applied the rule mentioned like that

```
'<info:([\w-]+)>'=>'main/generic/index'
```

Where info is the parameter and it makes the URL perfect like this

```
www.abc.com/xyz.html
```

where xyz can be a category or product. Now what i want is the 'category/product'.

Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
'category/<url:.+>' => 'category/product',
```

Where product function have a parameter to get slug

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this rule will have "category" as static word. In my case the category will change for each product. Will that work ?

Comment: then use '<cat:.+>/<url:.+>.html' => 'test/index', 
1st parameter is  category, 2nd is your slug and .html is static value

Comment: Thanks i will try that and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

```
'category/<slug:.+>' => 'category/product',
```

And  your product function will be

```
function actionProduct($slug){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me.

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Then your URL will "category/product" where controller is categoryController.php and action is actionProduct().